# neo4j how to do a distinct desc limit 10

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query

I want to get first 10 distinct teams.id .
How can I do this?

It's this query right?

```
match (chatitems)
with chatitems as C
match (teams)
with distinct teams as T
match (T)-[r:PartOf]-(C)
with C,  T.id as num order by num desc  
return {chatid:C.id, teams:collect(num)[0..10]}
```

**EDITED**

I have this query

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:CreatesChat]-(c:ChatItems)
with u,count(c.id) as chats
order by chats desc 
with chats,u
return chats,u limit 10
```

I need chats to use in another query

```
MATCH (c:ChatItems)-[:PartOf]->(t:TeamChatSession)-[:OwnedBy]-()
```

But I only need first 10 codes of chats.id and the user.id

How can I write this query to keep the 10 firs values of chats and user?

Comment: This query is too slow. It takes a long time and doesn't finish

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4j how to get first 10 desc codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358351/neo4j-how-to-get-first-10-desc-codes)

Comment: Yes, but I need distinct codes of teams.id.

Comment: If you want to improve the speed, please add labels to your nodes! Without labels, those first two matches (binding to chatitems and teams variables) are matching on every single node of every single type in your database!

Answer (score 0):

Again, for extra emphasis, add labels to your nodes! Your query will remain incredibly slow until you do!

So, assuming that you DO add labels, and assuming that your :Team nodes are already unique (you should have a unique constraint in place on :Team(id)), this is probably what you're looking for:

```
MATCH (team:Team)
WITH team ORDER BY team.id DESC LIMIT 10
...
```

You now have the top 10 teams in team id order, as you requested.

However, your query is doing other things, so I think you have other things you want to do with these top 10 teams. You'll have to tell us exactly what you want to do with these, what your final desired outcome is, if you want the kind of help you're looking for.

Here are a few guesses.

Do you want to get all of the chat IDs of chats that are a part of those top 10 teams? Then this should work:

```
MATCH (team:Team)
WITH team ORDER BY team.id DESC LIMIT 10
OPTIONAL MATCH (team)-[:PartOf]-(chat:Chat)
RETURN team.id, COLLECT(chat.id) AS chats
```

For each row you will have the team id, then a list of chat ids belonging to that team.

If this is not what you want, please make it very clear. It may also help if you stay with a single question and elaborate and clarify instead of making a new question or two directly related to the same problem on a daily basis.

I also highly recommend rereading the entire [developer manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/), and going through all the tutorials included in the browser application. Right now what you need most is a solid basic understanding of how Cypher queries work, and then to build on top of that. Attempting to ask questions here repeatedly without that basic knowledge will not serve you well.

Comment: I have a problem with labels. When I executed the query in neo4j browser don't return rows. Why is this?

Comment: The query assumes that your team nodes already have :Team labels, and that chat nodes already have :Chat labels. You must ensure you are applying labels to your nodes as you create them, or at least setting them later. Only after your nodes are labeled will the query work, as the query is explicitly looking for nodes with that label to match upon. The very first line to match on a :Team can only ever work if you have nodes labeled as :Team. Please reread the dev manual. Labels and their applications are a very basic part of neo4j that you must master.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check this evening.

Comment: I did progress with neo4j. I added labels. But I have a doubt. I edited my first question.